# What is the purpose of featureNS in Geoserver?

Tags: geoserver

I wonder why geoserver have featureNS field, if it can not be retrieved by any publicly made request. AFAIK generally featureNS is company URL plus project name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is returned in every WFS request response the GeoServer makes - for example search in the WFS GetCapabilities response for `topp` and you will find lines like:

```
<FeatureType xmlns:topp="http://www.openplans.org/topp">
```

You will also need to know the nameSpace URI for the features you are querying when making a WFS request:

```
<wfs:GetFeature service="WFS" version="1.1.0"
  xmlns:topp="http://www.openplans.org/topp"
  xmlns:wfs="http://www.opengis.net/wfs"
  xmlns:ogc="http://www.opengis.net/ogc"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.opengis.net/wfs
                      http://schemas.opengis.net/wfs/1.1.0/wfs.xsd">
  <wfs:Query typeName="topp:states">
    <ogc:Filter>
       <ogc:FeatureId fid="states.3"/>
    </ogc:Filter>
    </wfs:Query>
</wfs:GetFeature>
```

While it would be bad practice it is perfectly legal to use the same name for workspaces but assign them different URIs to distinguish them.